# Redmine 認証を用いた Git リポジトリが正常に動作しない

Tags: git, ubuntu, apache, redmine

Ubuntu 上で Redmine の認証を用いた Git 環境を構築しようとしていますが、Redmine 自体の動作は確認できているものの、Git リポジトリが正常に動作しません。

具体的には、`git clone` を実行すると認証ダイアログは表示されるものの、リポジトリにアクセスできていない様子。

```
$ git clone http://example.com/git/REPO.git
...
fatal: repository 'http://example.com/git/REPO.git' not found
```

Apache のログ (`/var/log/apache2/access_log`) を見ても、認証は通った後に 404 エラーが出ています。

```
xx.xxx.xx.xxx - - [14/May/2021:16:30:55 +0900] "HEAD /login?back_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 954 "-" "Git-Credential-Manager/ 
2.0.394.50751 (Windows; x86-64) CLR/.NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000"
xx.xxx.xx.xxx - cubick [14/May/2021:16:31:03 +0900] "GET /git/REPO.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 404 435 "-" "git/2.31.1.windows.1"
```

また、Apache のログレベルを debug に上げて動作を確認すると、エラーログには以下のように出力されていました。
git-http-backend が正常に動いていないようです。

```
[Fri May 14 16:31:03.978678 2021] [core:info] [pid 32123:tid 140292229400320] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:50884] AH00130: File does not exist: /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/REPO.git/info/refs
```

Redmine 認証を使った Git リポジトリ用の Apache 設定は以下の通りです。

**/etc/apache2/site-enabled/git.conf**

```
#LogLevel debug
PerlLoadModule Apache::Authn::Redmine

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/lib/git 
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER $REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER

ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Location /git/>
  PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Git Redmine"

  AuthUserFile /dev/null

  RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine;host=localhost"
  RedmineDbUser "redmine"
  RedmineDbPass "redmine"
  RedmineGitSmartHttp yes

  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

**環境:**
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Apache 2.4.41
Redmine 4.0.8
Ruby 2.6.7
Git 2.25.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache のデバッグレベルを上げて出力されたメッセージ "AH00130: File does not exist: ..." を頼りに調べたところ、以下の投稿で紹介されていた回答が参考になりました。

[Apache and git-http-backend - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25995863)

自分の環境では単に CGI モジュールが有効になっていなかったのが原因のようです。

以下のコマンドを実行して CGI モジュールを有効にし、プロセスを再起動後に Git リポジトリから正常に clone することができるようになりました。

```
$ sudo a2enmod cgi
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```